# VBA for a matrix with count of co-occurrences

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to produce a co-occurrence matrix in an Excel File. My data looks like this:

```
person1  A  
person1  B  
person2  A  
person2  C
person2  D
person3  A
person3  B
person4  A 
person4  C
...
```

But what I need is essentially a co-occurrence matrix that looks like this (it counts how often any of the combos between A-D occured):

```
    A   B   C   D
A   0   2   2   1
B   2   0   0   0
C   2   0   0   1
D   1   0   1   0
```

I unfortunately cannot find a useful VBA or Macro or any other approach (I am a beginner with VBA) - so if you have any idea how I could do this, please share.
I tried doing a Pivot but I cannot put the second column of the data on both of the two axis.
In R I would do this with crossprod() but I cannot get the data out of a save environment and cannot install R there either...
Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a dictionary with column B as key, collection of column A as value. Iterate the combinations and count the matches. Results written to Sheet2.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub CoOccurence()
    
    Dim dict As Object, k, ar, m, v1, v2
    Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    
    Dim lastrow As Long, i As Long, j As Long
    Dim a As String, b As String
   
    With Sheet1
        lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        For i = 1 To lastrow
            a = .Cells(i, "A")
            b = .Cells(i, "B")
           
            If Not dict.exists(b) Then
                dict.Add b, New Collection
            End If
            dict(b).Add a
        Next
    End With
    
    ' results
    ar = dict.keys
    i = dict.Count
    ReDim m(1 To i, 1 To i)
    With Sheet2
        For i = 1 To UBound(m)
            ' headers
            .Cells(1, i + 1) = ar(i - 1)
            .Cells(i + 1, 1) = ar(i - 1)
            ' counts
            For j = 1 To UBound(m, 2)
                a = ar(i - 1)
                b = ar(j - 1)
                m(i, j) = 0
                If a <> b Then
                    For Each v1 In dict(a)
                       For Each v2 In dict(b)
                           If v1 = v2 Then m(i, j) = m(i, j) + 1
                       Next
                    Next
                End If
               .Cells(i + 1, j + 1) = m(i, j)
            Next
        Next
    End With    
    MsgBox "Done"
End Sub
```